# Second optional input to \chapter to rename bookmark

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, chapters, bookmarks

I would like to include a second optional argument in `\chapter`'s definition to be able to give the bookmark a name different from the one displayed on the toc.

The reason for this is that on the toc sub- and superscripts can be typeset, whereas this is not possible in the bookmarks.

This is my work-around

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}
\usepackage{ifthen,twoopt}

\def\whyIsThisNeeded{
  \let\origchap\chapter
  \let\origsec\section

  \renewcommandtwoopt\chapter[3][toc][bm]{
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{toc}}{\def\ontoc{##3}}{\def\ontoc{##1}}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{##2}{bm}}{\def\inbm{##3}}{\def\inbm{##2}}

    \origchap[\ontoc]{##3}
    \phantomsection\pdfbookmark[0]{\inbm}{\inbm}
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}
    }
  \renewcommandtwoopt\section[3][toc][bm]{
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=-2}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{toc}}{\def\ontoc{##3}}{\def\ontoc{##1}}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{##2}{bm}}{\def\inbm{##3}}{\def\inbm{##2}}

    \origsec[\ontoc]{##3}
    \phantomsection\pdfbookmark[1]{\inbm}{\inbm}
    \hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=2}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\whyIsThisNeeded
\chapter[1st chapter on toc][chapter 1]{first chapter in document}
\section[section on toc][section bookmark]{section in doc}
\chapter[2nd chapter on toc][chapter 2]{second chapter in document}
\end{document}
```

and it does exactly what I want, however

1. Why is `\whyIsThisNeeded` needed?
2. How can I query the previous 'bookmarksdepth' and reset it afterwards?
3. Do I really need to redefine all `\chapter\section\sub...` commands individually?
4. How can I define the command in the form of `\chapter[toc-name]{doc-name}[bm-name]`?

Comment: Why don't you use `\texorpdfstring`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wasn't aware of that command, that's indeed the simplest solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than multiplying the optional arguments, I propose a key-value syntax:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { roepo/chapter }
 {
  toc .tl_set:N = \l_roepo_chapter_toc_tl,
  bookmark .tl_set:N = \l_roepo_chapter_bookmark_tl,
  header .tl_set:N = \l_roepo_chapter_header_tl,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Chapter}{sO{}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \chapter*{#3}
   }
   {
    \roepo_chapter:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \roepo_chapter:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_roepo_chapter_toc_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_roepo_chapter_bookmark_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_roepo_chapter_header_tl { #2 }
  \keys_set:nn { roepo/chapter } { #1 }
  \chapter
   [\texorpdfstring{\l_roepo_chapter_toc_tl}{\l_roepo_chapter_bookmark_tl}]
   {#2}
   \chaptermark{\l_roepo_chapter_header_tl}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\Chapter[
  toc=Short title for toc,
  header=Short for head,
  bookmark=A long title with f(x),
]{A long title with $f(x)$}

\section{A section}

\kant
\end{document}
```

If some keys are not used, the chapter title in the mandatory argument is used. Similar definitions can be made for the other sectional units.

[image]

Comment: This works like a charm, and to me it actually _is_ magic, as I don't understand what's happening. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: This kind of answers my question (3), how about (1), (2) and (4)? It might be good to know even though your key-value proposal is a nicer solution in this case...

Comment: @D.Roepo (1) `hyperref` redefines `\chapter` and friends at begin document; (2) you don't need that; (3) yes.